# Scoring/storing Cricket games

Tags: database, database-design, file-format

Two parts to this question:

- Are there any existing file formats or software libraries that can be used for scoring, archiving and/or analysing cricket games?
- Are there any examples of database schemas suitable for recording all of the details of a cricket game?

Comment: This implies that someone fully understands a game which goes on for 3 days, yet pauses for tea in the middle.

Comment: Yes, speaking as an American, you'd first have to convince that the problem of understanding cricket scoring has been solved in the abstract before looking for existing software to do it.

Comment: Five days, not three. And tea _and_ lunch breaks.

Answer (score 8):

Cricksheet offers ball-by-ball match data for the recent year in yaml format. The specification of their yaml format can be found here - http://cricsheet.org/format/ .

But, I really don't understand this **3 day** thing everyone keeps talking about. Test matches last 5 days, One-day matches last, well, one day and T20 matches last close to 4 hours.

Only exhibition first-class matches or practice matches are played for 3 days, and I am wondering why anyone is talking about it here if that is what they are indeed talking about.

Answer (score 1):

As you will know cricket is a complex game and commentator needs lots of stats to rehash over 3 days or more.

So short of someone sharing proprietary info, you probably better off designing an XML schema(may be) to store the data.

Good luck